# Cell Resizing using Autolayout in IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I was trying to resize cell using content size but I came to know that in  IOS 8 you can resize the cell using Autolayout. I tried the same but I could not get the exact UI. I have a TableView in UIView Controller. Here is my code **viewcontroller.m** :-

```
@implementation MessageViewController
@synthesize  messageTable;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.messageTable.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0;
    self.messageTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

   [super viewDidLoad];


  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
      self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
  self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO;
  _txtField=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 220, 30)];
  [_txtField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
  _txtField.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
  _txtField.clipsToBounds = YES;

  _txtField.text=@"Hello";



[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:_txtField];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(265.0, 5, 50.0, 30.0);

[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:button];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]

                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


// table view data is being set here
_messageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
           @"Data 2 ",@"Data 1 Data 1Data 1Data 1Data 1Data 1Data 1Data     1Data 1D",@"Data 8 ",
               @"Data 9 ", nil];
     [self.messageTable reloadData];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The UI looks something like this :-

[image]

And the constraints on label are :- 
[image]

Help needed :)

EDIT :-

[image]

Cell

[image]

Comment: Why not calculate each row's height in heightForRowAtIndexPath ??

Comment: I want to add more elements in the cell like UIImage etc. Autolayout makes it easy to give spacing and margins that's why I was going with autolayout.

Comment: Autolayout can help you organize you views inside the cell, and setting the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will make the view layout taking into account what the cell view size is. So for example your margin spaces will still be done properly using your constraints.

Comment: I am not saying not to use Autolayout, but you will get a better result if you implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath and calculate your height.
The only calculation you will need in your case if i understood from what you said is the height of the label.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the expected output is meant to be or what the exact problem is. Is it that the label is not sizing correctly (have you changed it's background colour to check it is resizing) or is it that too many cells are being drawn? You haven't added any tableview delegate methods so I assume you have checked that the correct values are being returned from each one. Finally, have you tried the view debugger (and checked the constraints in the cells if that is what you think is wrong)?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/
You can try this link to autoresize your label in ios 8 only.

and also dont forget to add below line in your viewdidload.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution for Swift.  Expands the selected cell, collapses all others.

Inform tableview of cell sizes upon begin/end updates being called:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let cellHeight: CGFloat
    if indexPath == selectedIndex {
      cellHeight = 150
    } else {
      cellHeight = 50
    }

    return cellHeight
}
```

Trigger begin/end updates when cell is tapped:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected row: \(indexPath.row)")

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    //will trigger cell resizing
    tableView.endUpdates()
  }
```